# How can I make webpack recognize a custom index.js file?

Tags: indexing, webpack, resolve

How can I make webpack recognize a custom index.js file?

For example, I want webpack to override `index.js` with `index.ios.js` when importing from a folder.

```
import thing from './thing'
```

I tried the following configuration, but it doesn't work . . .

```
{
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.ios.js',
      '.js'
    ]
  }
}
```